# Prove that $g(x)=\int_a^bf(x+t)dt$ is differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continous function and $a,b\in\mathbb{R}, a<b$. Lets define $g(x)=\int_a^bf(x+t)dt$.
Prove that $g(x)=\int_a^bf(x+t)dt$ is differentiable and that its derivative is $g'(x)=f(x+b)-f(x+a)$. Using properties of the integral, I get this from definition.

$$lim_{h\to 0}\int_a^b \frac{f(x+h+t)-f(x+t)}{h}dt=??\int_a^bf'(x+t)dt=f(x+b)-f(x+a)$$ I was thinking I could go with the limit under the integral, but there is no assumption about $f$ being differentiable, so the calculation after the ?? seems to me wrong, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac1h\int_a^b\left(f(x+h+t)-f(x+t)\right) dt\stackrel{u:=x+t}=\frac1h\int_{x+a}^{x+b}\left(f(u+h)-f(u)\right)\,du$$

and since $\;f\;$ is continuous it has a primitive function, say $\;F\;$ , so

$$\frac1h\int_{x+a}^{x+b}\left(f(u+h)-f(u)\right)\,du=\frac1h\left(F(x+b+h)-F(x+a+h)-F(x+b)+ F(x+a)\right)=$$

$$=\frac{F(x+b+h)-F(x+b)}h-\frac{F(x+a+h)-F(x+a)}h\xrightarrow[h\to0]{}F'(x+b)-F'(x+a)=$$

$$=f(x+b)-f(x+a)$$

Fill in details.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: use a substitution, and the fundamental theorem of calculus.