# Prove $g'(x) = f(x + b) - f(x+a)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

> Let $f\colon \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $a<b$.
>
> Let $g\colon \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined as $g(x) = \int_{a}^{b}f(x+t) dt$.
>
> Prove that $g$ is differentiable and that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$, $g'(x) = f(x + b) - f(x+a)$

I'm not at all sure where to start. Should we simply apply the fundamental theorem of calculus here?

Comment: Yeah, it is possible to apply FTC with change of variable

Comment: Tip: use $\rightarrow$, not "->". Code is ```\rightarrow```.

Comment: Thanks, @K.defaoite. Fixed.

Comment: Link to essentially the same problem. Couldn't find it at the time I asked the question.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3327259/prove-that-gx-int-abfxtdt-is-differentiable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $F(x)=\int_0^x f(t)\,dt$. Then by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus 
$$
F'(x)=f(x).
$$ Changing variables $u=x+t$ we get
$$
g(x)=\int_{a}^{b} f(x+t)\,dt=\int_{a+x}^{b+x} f(u)\,du=F(b+x)-F(x+a).
$$
Differentiating the above we finally have
$$
g'(x)=F'(b+x)-F'(x+a)=f(b+x)-f(x+a).
$$

Answer (score 1):

We will show that $g(x)$ is differentiable and the derivative is $g'(x)=f(x+b)-f(x+a)$.

Our strategy is going to show that the following limit exists which will give us the derivative we wanted

$$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{g(x+h)-g(x)}{h}$$
$$=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{\int_{a}^{b}f(x+t+h)-\int_{a}^{b}f(x+t)}{h}$$

Using $u=t+h$ substitution, (simple stuff)

$$=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{\int_{a+h}^{b+h}f(x+u)-\int_{a}^{b}f(x+t)}{h}$$

Since $u$ and $t$ are merely a symbol (placeholders really)

$$=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{\int_{a+h}^{b+h}f(x+t)-\int_{a}^{b}f(x+t)}{h}$$

$$=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{\int_{b}^{b+h}f(x+t)-\int_{a}^{a+h}f(x+t)}{h}$$

Hmm using L'Hopital and FTC, we have

$$=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}f(x+b+h)-f(x+a+h)$$

Now by continuity of $f$,

$$=f(\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}x+b+h)-f(\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}x+a+h)$$
$$=f(x+b)-f(x+a)$$